# Does Quectel's BG96 support HTTP(S) protocol?

Tags: gsm

In the official website's datasheet, it says it supports HTTP(s) but when I googled the specs, it says nothing about HTTP(s) but supports TCP,FTP etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTTP(S) is supported.

You can download the HTTP(S) AT command manual from here:
[Quectel Technical Documents](https://www.quectel.com/support/downloadb/TechnicalDocuments.htm)